# How to use nativewind for react native expo with react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css, react-native-navigation

I've been trying to integrate tailwindcss to my react native expo project and it was working fine when i applied the tailwind classNames in the App.js , but as soon  as I added react navigation to  it and tried using the styles in Homscreen.js component the styles did not show and nothing happened .  It  was just bare text.

This is my tailwindcss.config.js file

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
   
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

this is my babel.config.js file

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
  };
};
```

this is my App.js file

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Homescreen from './screen/Homescreen';

export default function App() {

 const Stack=createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Homescreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
   
  );
}
```

this is my Homescreen component Homescreen.js file

```js
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const Homescreen = () => {

  return (
   <View className="flex-1 justify-center text-center">
    <Text className="text-green-700">
      HOme screen styles test
    </Text>
   </View>
  )
}

export default Homescreen
```

The code images and results
[tailwindcss.config.js and babel.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qhvs.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD1Hv.png)
[homescreen and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd5Jj.png)

Answer (score 3):

Customizing your "tailwind.config.js" file for new directories in your react native expo app with react navigation is necessary but if your nativewind styling still won't work properly, then stopping the expo server and instead of starting it like this `expo start`, do this `expo start -c` to wipe the cache that nativewind adds to restart the server clean.

Source: https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/troubleshooting

When customizing your "tailwind.config.js" file, after creating your custom "screens" directory or any other component directory, then add that directory path `"./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"` to the "content:" property in your "tailwind.config.js". You don't have to but should delete `"./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],` That will keep your code clean and is really just for instructional purposes, see below:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution

Create a custom directory for your screens or the other components then add that directory to your tailwind.config.css

In my case the custom directory i created is "screens"

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
   
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Remember to remove `"./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]`, or sometimes it will not work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Customizing my "tailwind.config.js" file and using expo start -c worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `expo start -c` fixes the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
   
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./Components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"], // Make sure there should not be any <custom directory>, else it will not work
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Edit the tailwind.config.js like this and move HomeScreen.js to the Components folder. No one can stop it from working!!!